# Loop through python array, set specific values to a specified column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried many things but still stuck. This is mostly because I'm failing to understand how python loops through an array or what options I have to loop through it.

I want to build an array: 4 columns, 18 rows.

I need the first column of each row to be a persons name in the person_list. Every 3 rows of my array I would then increment to the next person.

It would seem that my loop is not looping through the array the way I intended. It seems that it sets all values in the first column equal to the person_list value.

```
person_list = ["person1", "person2","person3","person4","person5","person6"]
my_array = [[0]*4]*len(person_list)*3

i=0
j=1
for row in my_array:
    while j <= 3:
        row[0] = person_list[i]
        j+=1
    j=1
    i+=1
```

So the goal would be the resulting array

```
[
["person1", 0, 0, 0],
["person1", 0, 0, 0],
["person1", 0, 0, 0],
["person2", 0, 0, 0],
["person2", 0, 0, 0],
["person2", 0, 0, 0],
["person3", 0, 0, 0],
["person3", 0, 0, 0],
...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to stem from the way `my_array` was initialized. Each row is 'nested' with the other rows, by that I mean if you try to modify my_array[0], you will end up modify all the remaining rows. Here is an example to illustrate that:

```
my_array[0].insert(0, 'hello_world')
# this prints:
# [['hello_world', 0, 0, 0],
   ['hello_world', 0, 0, 0],
   ....
   ['hello_world', 0, 0, 0]]
```

To get around, this you can use numpy to initialize your array of zeros or do something like this:

```
my_array = [[0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(18)]
```

To make the code slight more concise and print the expected output, you can then do the following:

```
for i in range(len(person_list)):
    # person1 : idx 0, 1, 2
    # person2 : idx 3, 4, 5
    # ...
    end_idx = (i + 1) * 3
    start_idx = end_idx - 3

    for sub_arr in arr[start_idx:end_idx]:
        sub_arr.insert(0, person_list[i])
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo `%` to increment at certain intervals. For example, `row%3==0` will return `True` at multiples of 3. FYI in your above code you were not resetting the row variable  every interval of 3.

```
person_list = ["person1", "person2","person3","person4","person5","person6"]
my_array = [[0]*4]*len(person_list)*3

j=0
i=0
for row in my_array:
    if j%3==0:
        row[0] = person_list[i]
        i+=1
    j+=1 # increment the row here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is good in your code, you are just multiplying it by 3 :

```
person_list = ["person1", "person2","person3","person4","person5","person6"]
my_array = [[0]*4]*len(person_list)

i=0
j=1
for row in my_array:
    while j <= 3:
        row[0] = person_list[i]
       j+=1
    j=1
    i+=1
```

I think its this like which needs to change from `my_array = [[0]*4]*len(person_list)*3` to `my_array = [[0]*4]*len(person_list)`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer to demonstrate my expected resulting array. I need 18 rows and multiplying by 3 gave me the correct dimensions in the resulting array. So the x3 is required.

Answer (score 0):

So I think NeuralX was helpful in pointing out the way I create the array is not going to work for what I intend to do to it. He is absolutely correct when I run a change it will update every entry in the final array.

In more searching with working with nested lists, I have found how I should create the array so that I can update nested lists individually by looping through it. The final results are going to be below.

```
person_list = ["person1", "person2","person3","person4","person5","person6"]

# The way I create the array appears the be the main root cause here. I need to create it like this
my_array = [[0 for x in range(4)] for y in range(sum(person_assessments))]

i=0
j=0
for person in person_list:

    for assessment in range(1, 4):
        my_array[i][0] = person
        # print(person, ", ", assessment)
        # print(i,", ", j,", ", person)

        i+=1

    j += 1

print(my_array)
```